# Reusing view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am unclear on how to reuse view controllers. If you have created a view controller subclass that does some stuff (doesn't really matter what it does, just that it does what you need in the view), can it be used with a different view or should it be subclassed again?

In other words, if I need the exact same functionality in a view in a different part of my app, can I use the original view controller and just add the outlets from the new view? Or should I subclass the custom controller and give the view its "own" view controller?

Comment: Usually each controller has it's own view. But of course, to avoid code duplication, views should be modeled in such a way that they CAN be reused. If you have trouble on this matter, maybe you need to rethink your MVC structure.

Comment: So is it "correct" to have outlets from multiple identical views in the same controller?

Comment: "If it's stupid, but it works, then it's not stupid."

Comment: Good question, you can definitely and infact encouraged to use the same view controller. Though not fully in line with what you are thinking, take the case where you have the same view controller with different xibs for iPhone and iPad. I found this post interesting where it explains having the same xib with ~ipad.xib naming convention

Comment: I have a number of cases where the same view controller is used for two or three different XIBs.  Elements that don't exist in a given XIB will be reflected into the VC as nil values for the IBOutlets.  (I also have a couple of cases where the same XIB is used for multiple different VCs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create two xibs for the view controller.

If you have the files...

```
MyViewController.m
MyViewController.h
```

Then you could add the xibs...

```
MyViewControllerXib1
MyViewControllerXib2
```

Just make the "File's Owner" MyViewController.

Then when you need the UI layout from the first XIB you can call...

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewControllerXib1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

When you need the second UI you can call...

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewControllerXib2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

The object you get will be the same but the nib laying out the UI will change.

**ANOTHER APPROACH**

Just thinking out loud here.

You could also create a ViewController without a nib.

Then create two subclasses of this each WITH a nib. Now you have code reuse and separate layouts but you can also make fine control tweaks to each of the subclasses of your "master" controller.

You can then create as many subclasses as you like from this master view controller.

**USING STORYBOARDS**

Just drag a new ViewController object onto the storyboard. Change the class to be the view controller class and set up the UI and drag the controls to the code etc... You will then have two screens that look different but share the same functionality code.

This is just the same as what I said at first but using storyboard instead.

Comment: I am just learning IOS development and know nothing about xibs or nibs. I have just been using Storyboards to layout the app. And I may be getting my terminology confused as well. What I want to do is drag out a second view controller into another part of my app. Then I need to assign a controller class in the Identity Inspector. Can I reuse an existing subclass or should I create a new subclass?

Comment: Ah I see. Yes you can do it with storyboards also. From what I understand you have a VC (VC1) at some point in your navigation. You then move around in the app and get to another view controller (VC2) which has the same functionality as VC1 but a different layout. (correct?). In that case just drag a new VC onto the storyboard and set the class to be the same but change the layout. This is essentially what I said but using storyboards instead of separate xibs.